# Android O in Android Emulater has not respond

Tags: android

I want to run some google android samples，but compileSdkVersion need "android-O"，I do not have a real phone, so I decided to use Android Emulator ,when I run it, it has no respond.

Android O

[image: Android O]

Comment: Do you have a bad computer? (meaning low ram, bad processor, etc). If you do, what you are experiencing may be because the emulator takes longer to acquire the resources to complete the boot

Comment: Nothing helped?

Answer (score 0):

> compileSdkVersion need "android-O"

This doesn't require you to run the application just on Android O devices. `minSdkVersion` is the field that defines the minimum supported API version. You can run those applications on any phone which has a newer or same version of Android as declared in the `minSdkVersion`.

Read more here: [Configure Your Build | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/index.html)

> compileSdkVersion specifies the Android API level Gradle should use to compile your app. This means your app can use the API features included in this API level and lower.

---

If you still really want to run it on an Emulator, make sure you have:

- CPU ABI set to x86 or x86_64
- Resolution set to something like 480 x 800
- RAM set to minimum required by the API version you are trying to emulate

This will ensure that it takes up minimum resources and works even on older/lo-fi machines.